# Xamarin.Forms Dispatcher.BeginInvokeOnMainThread causing deadlock on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, deadlock

I have an activity indicator on my Page called `indicator`. 
I want to Animate it, so that it cycles through every color. For this i'm using this method:

```cs
public static async Task ActivityIndicatorRainbow(ActivityIndicator indicator, int colorDelay)
        {
            for (double i = 0; i < 1; i += 0.01)
            {
                Color c = Color.FromHsla(i, 0.5, 0.5);

                indicator.Dispatcher.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=> indicator.Color = c);

                await Task.Delay(colorDelay);
            }
        }
```

And in my ButtonPressed Method i call that using this:

```cs
activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
await Task.Run(() => ActivityIndicatorRainbow(activityIndicator, 10));
```

On Android this works fine, the Indicator spins while changing colors. But on iOS the Indicator stands still until the Rainbow Task finishes and then it starts spinning.

I have already tried  Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync() with the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in iOS Native Develop Tools (**Xcode**) by using **Objective-C** to change color each time less than 1 second, it occurs the same phenomnenon with Xamarin Forms . Then I think `ActivityIndicator` in iOS not supports changing color each time less than one seconds .

Therefore ,the easy way to make it work is to modfiy code as follow with every one second to change color  :

```
activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
await Task.Run(() => ActivityIndicatorRainbow(activityIndicator, 1000));
```

If need to less than one second to change color in iOS ,you can have a try with custom renderer to custom a `ActivityIndicator` by using Navtive mtethod [**CADisplayLink**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/coreanimation.cadisplaylink?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) or **[DispatchSource.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corefoundation.dispatchsource.timer?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)** .

Comment: Ok, thanks for your effort. I think i will make this feature Android only then because its really just cosmetic